# nvidia 3d display output with only 24Hz refresh rate

Tags: nvidia-geforce, 3d

I m having a [Philips 238G4DHSD/94](http://www.philips.co.in/c-p/238G4DHSD_94/brilliance-lcd-monitor-with-smartimage/overview) 3D monitor.

I m having a Nvidia GTX 460 graphics card showing in NVidia control panel that 3d resolution supported are - 
1080p, 1920 X 1080 at the refresh rate **24Hz**

while the monitor information complains that the recommended refresh rate is 60Hz.

How do I get refresh rate at 60Hz or this is not supported by the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually not supported by the monitor. While the monitor says its "3d". What it really means is that it will take a 2d input and convert it to 3d through the monitor. In order for 3d to work through the Nvidia GPU you will need a monitor with a refresh rate of 120hz or higher, as well as needing either a monitor with built in 3d Vision 1/2 sensor with glasses, or by having a Nvidia 3d Vision Kit. Your monitor's optimum refresh rate is 60hz @ 1080p which is not recommended for nvidia 3d.

I'm sorry to say but your monitor is not supported of proper nvidia 3d viewing.

If you'd like to see a list of supported hardware please check out this page. It lists all monitors/laptops/tvs/projectors that are currently able to be used by 3d Vision Technology. http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-system-requirements.html